# easy_localization have fallback values for keys on other languages

Tags: flutter, localization, translation

When working with [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) for localization, and base translation done in EN, I want my 2nd language to show keys if they are present in 2nd language json file, but if they are not, to consume `en.json` equivalent value. Issue is that by default this package shows key that doesn't exist in JSON file, instead of fallback translation file value. Is there a way to override this?

Usage of the plugin in `main.dart` file

```
runApp(
  EasyLocalization(
    child: MyApp(),
    useOnlyLangCode: true,
    fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en'),
      Locale('es'),
    ],
    path: 'lang',
  ),
);
```

And when I want to translate a key that exists in `en.json`, but doesn't exist in `es.json` file it looks like this:

```
tr('appTitle');
```

Expected result would be "Hello world", but I get "appTitle" on the screen.

Comment: Add a piece of code showing your use of the `EasyLocalization` widget

Comment: Done. Implementation looks really straight forward, but I haven't found a way of showing en.json translation instead of the missing one in es.json file.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: any solutions ? I am facing the same issue !

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since I just ran into the same problem:

There is now(?) a parameter "useFallbackTranslations" that you have to set to true. Indeed a bit counterintuitive, because one would assume that setting fallbackLocale should be enough.

```
EasyLocalization(
fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
supportedLocales: const [
  Locale('en'),
  Locale('es'),
  Locale('de'),
],
useOnlyLangCode: true,
useFallbackTranslations: true, // <------
path: 'assets/i18n',
child: const MyApp(),
))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `EasyLocalization` settings in `runApp`:

```
runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
        useOnlyLangCode: true,
        useFallbackTranslations: true,
        path: LanguageManager.langAssetPath,
        supportedLocales: LanguageManager.instance.supportedLocales,
        startLocale: LanguageManager.instance.dlLocale,
        fallbackLocale: LanguageManager.instance.dlLocale,
        child: const App(),
    ), 
);
```

And the separated `LanguageManager` class

```
class LanguageManager {
    LanguageManager._init();
    static LanguageManager get instance => _instance ??= LanguageManager._init();

    static LanguageManager? _instance;

    static const langAssetPath = 'assets/translations';
    final dlLocale = const Locale('en', 'US'); // necessary
    final enLocale = const Locale('en');
    final trLocale = const Locale('tr');

    List<Locale> get supportedLocales => [dlLocale, enLocale, trLocale];

    // constants
    static const supportedLanguages = ['en', 'tr'];

    Locale getCurrentLocale() {
    return supportedLanguages.contains(getCurrentLang)
        ? Locale(getCurrentLang)
        : const Locale('en');
  }

    String get getCurrentLang => Platform.localeName.substring(0, 2);
}
```

Finally `assets/translations` folder must `en-US.json`, `en.json` and `tr.json`

Don't forget generating

PS: This solution is from Veli Bacik in Turkey